# How to pin an android ongoing notification

Tags: android-notifications

I want to create an andriod ongoing notification that will always stay on the top of all other notification including notifications that will arrive after the notification were shown.

What should I do to acheive this behaviour?

Comment: It's absolutely not clear what you're talking about.

Comment: I created an android onging notification that can't be clear. I want it to be allwys the notification that shows on the top. the problem is that whn new (ongoing) notifications shows they show obbove of my notification. I'm looking for a way that after new notifications show my notification will go back up to be the higher notification. thanks.

Comment: Well, you should edit your question to say that you're talking about Android then :)